# HTTP Request with .NET Core resulting in a 403 Forbidden error

Tags: .net-core

I'm trying to make a web request to a 3rd party endpoint using .NET Core 2.  The endpoint requires authentication with a client certificate and a username and password.  So far everything I try results in a 403 (Forbidden) error.  I've tried the following so far:

```
try
{
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    handler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
    handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
    handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
    handler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(certificate));

    var client = new HttpClient(handler);
    var result = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(e);
     throw;
 }
```

I've also tried:

```
try
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    var cert = new X509Certificate2(certificate);
    request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
    request.Method = "GET";

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    throw;
}
```

So far I'm just trying to do a GET but eventually I'll need to do a POST.

As I said above, both result in a 403.  If I run the second sample against the .NET Framework it works just fine.  Also, if I have Fiddler running then I get an OK status returned and not a 403.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong that is preventing .NET Core from successfully connecting to an endpoint?

Comment: Maybe you are missing to pass some headers, something like Accept-Language, Content-Type.

Comment: I've tried adding different headers and so far nothing has worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up switching the code to what I have below and that did the trick. I set the ClientCertificateOption to be Automatic and I removed manually specifying the certificate.

```
try
{
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    handler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
    handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic;
    handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;

    var client = new HttpClient(handler);
    var result = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    throw;
}
```